# RxJS Angular : Listen to one observable and use the latest value from two other

Tags: angular, rxjs, reactive-programming

I'm using Redux and RxJS Angular (4) implementation to manage state & actions reactivly into my app.

I'm listening to one event (a change on the selected product ID in a product list) so we call it `selectedProductId$`.

When the related emitter emits a new selectedId value, I want to do a `switchMap` from this Observable value, along with the latest emitted values from two other Observables (let's say; `productDetails$` and `productComments$`).

So the "triggering change" should be the selectedProductID and we would do a `switchMap` with latest values of productDetails and productComments.

I tried this :

```
// subscribed to the 3 observable passed in combineLatest
 fetchProduct$: Observable<any>;
 this.fetchProduct$ = Observable.combineLatest(
       this.selectedProductId$,
       this.productComments$,
       this.productDetails$
 ).switchMap(
       result => Observable.of(
         {
           'uuid': result[0],
           'comments': result[1],
           'details': result[2]
         }
      )
 );
```

Then I subscribe to this observable and put a break point on the value passed :

```
this.fetchProductSubscription = this.fetchProduct$.subscribe(result => this.someFn(value));
```

It works but is called each time one of the three Observables detects state change. I also tried Observable.forkJoin, but from the doc, it waits for the three Observable to emit new value, which make me weird state as I get comments from another Webservice and it can retrieve it when the next product Id is selected.

Observable.merge is also not a solution as it will emit only values one by one on one "channel".

I'm not fully used to reactive programming and maybe I don't clearly see an obvious solution, but right know I would love a hint or some help to solve this problem :( 
Thanks a lot

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`withLatestFrom`](http://rxmarbles.com/#withLatestFrom), which works similar to `combineLatest()` but fires each time the source observable fires. Example (for rxjs 5.5):

```
this.fetchProduct$ = 
  this.selectedProductId$.pipe(
   withLatestFrom(
       this.productComments$,
       this.productDetails$
   ));
```

Or for earlier versions:

```
this.fetchProduct$ = 
  this.selectedProductId$.withLatestFrom(
       this.productComments$,
       this.productDetails$
   );
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tips! I didn't know this withLatestFrom method I'll go with this

Answer (score 1):

First, let's merge the "extra" observables that you don't want to trigger any changes.

```
const extras$ = Observable.combineLatest(this.productComments$, this.productDetails$);
```

Now, we watch for emissions in our "interesting" observable, and just use the latest values from our extras.

```
cosnt allTogether$ = this.selectedProductId$.withLatestFrom(extras$,
    ([uuid, [comments, details]]) => ({uuid, comments, details}) );
```

Now feel free to subscribe to `allTogether$`.

Comment: My bad you also use withLatestFrom I removed my previous comment. thanks to you too !

Comment: @Alex no worries. Magnattic's answer passes the observables directly to the function, which I feel is cleaner, but have forgotten about.